# IntelliSense engine crashed for file with ranges

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, visual-studio-2022, std-ranges

Visual Studio 2022 (recent version, 17.7.7) **IntelliSense** crashes with the code below.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Copy/paste the code to the IDE
2. Change the code, for example uncomment `std::vector<int> values2(10);`

In some seconds the IDE will show the message:

> IntelliSense engine crashed for file ‘…’

**Questions**

1. Am I the only person who has this issue?
2. Am I correct that the code itself is correct?
3. Could it be related to the [IntelliSense engine crashed for file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IntelliSense-engine-crashed-for-file/10329046) or [IntelliSense engine crashes on Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.4 when using std::views::ranges](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IntelliSense-engine-crashes-on-Visual-St/10476538) bug reports?
4. Are there any known workarounds?

**The code**

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values(10);
    // std::vector<int> values2(10);

    auto range = std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end());
}
```

Comment: I am using VS2022 17.8.2. I tested the snippet and did not encounter your problem.

Comment: May be unrelated, but I faced repeated IntelliSense crash in VS2022 17.8.0 Preview 6, for much larger C++ file. Enabling 64-bit intellisense, fixed it for me.  Text Editor  > C++ >IntelliSense > Enable 64-bit Intellisense

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, thank you for the feedback. Somehow my VS missed the recent updates; usually it came with notification, now it missed since the version 17.7.7. With the recent update the issue (seems) to have disappeared. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Surojit, thanks. I already had 64-bit IntelliSense enabled. I met this issue with larger file too, I just narrowed the looking range step by step to extract this minimal reproducible example. No issues on large file, as well, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the recent update of Visual Studio 2022 the issue have been resolved.